# What could someone malicious do with these three piece of information regarding my bank account?

Tags: bank-account, fraud, germany, security

The three pieces of information are: bank account number, my mobile phone number used for online banking and my address associated with my bank account.
I am in Germany.

Comment: Do you also wonder about possible attacks? (social engineering, malware on your mobile phone, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you could now get spam calls and mailings, nothing negative at all. With your account number, anyone can send you money (which you probably wouldn't mind), but otherwise, no access is possible.

In Germany, every company and many people publish their account number, so they can receive payment. Every invoice contains address, phone number, and account numbers of the company that bills you, so you are able to send them money to pay the invoice.

Nobody can access the money or details of your account with only the name and number; it needs your online login user id and password, or your (government issued) ID to do so. You don't need to worry at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to this: https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/blogs/techftc/2016/06/your-mobile-phone-account-could-be-hijacked-identity-thief It is possible that the malicious person could make the telephone company swap the sim card of the victim (“SIM swap” scam) to gain access to the victim's account. How does that scam work if the criminal does not know the password or ID? Would I be safe from such scam?

Comment: This article is about the US. The situation there is very different; as IDs are not mandatory to have, the knowledge of personal information is often sufficient to get access. Google any contractor or club in Germany, and most of them will the info right on their website.

Comment: With the account number + name, you cannot only send money, you can also withdraw money ([Direct debit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_debit), [*Lastschrift*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lastschrift) in German).

Comment: @unor , You have to be registered for that, and you are legally and financially responsible for abuse. It's not like any Joe could just draw money from you that way.

Comment: @Aganju: But "someone" (not necessarily everyone) could do it, so it seems to fall under what OP is asking about.